# fedora bluetooth not working

Tags: fedora, bluetooth

### EDIT :

after sleeping, the bluetooth works again for no particular reason ... Christmas magic maybe ...

---

---

My bluetooth suddenly stopped working.

In the settings I didn't even have access to the button to turn it on or off.

The command `systemctl status bluetooth`
give me

```
➜ systemctl status bluetooth 
○ bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Dec 17 10:13:18 fedora systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Dec 17 10:14:06 fedora systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
```

After a

```
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
systemctl restart bluetooth
```

the `systemctl status bluetooth`
give me

```
➜ systemctl status bluetooth 
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-12-17 10:14:30 CET; 3s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 5335 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18989)
     Memory: 1.9M
        CPU: 52ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─5335 /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Dec 17 10:14:30 fedora systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Dec 17 10:14:30 fedora bluetoothd[5335]: Bluetooth daemon 5.62
Dec 17 10:14:30 fedora bluetoothd[5335]: Starting SDP server
Dec 17 10:14:30 fedora systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Dec 17 10:14:30 fedora bluetoothd[5335]: Bluetooth management interface 1.21 initialized
```

The `enable` button on the bluetooth setting reappeared but it does nothing...

But now i'm enable to do `bluetoothctl --monitor`, with a `list` I have 0 result. With `devices` I have `No default controller available`.

A cold reboot do nothing too.

Anything is open `rfkill list`

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

For `dmesg`

```
➜ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[   99.703042] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   99.703105] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[   99.703105] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   99.703108] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   99.703109] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   99.703111] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  108.295602] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  108.295605] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  108.295608] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

```
➜ dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn
x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.
 #5 #6 #7
ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.TPLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS01], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS02], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS03], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS04], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS05], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS06], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS07], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS08], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS09], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS10], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS11], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS12], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS13], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS14._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.HS14._PLD], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR1], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.USR2], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS01], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS02], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS03], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS04], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS05], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS06], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS07], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS08], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS09], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS10], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.I2C2.TPD0], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.I2C3.TPL1], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._ON], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._OFF], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/psobject-220)
i8042: PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp
device-mapper: core: CONFIG_IMA_DISABLE_HTABLE is disabled. Duplicate IMA measurements will not be recorded in the IMA log.
integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
ipmi_si: Unable to find any System Interface(s)
usb 1-14: device descriptor read/64, error -71
wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: WQ data block query control method not found
wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: WQ data block query control method not found
wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: WQ data block query control method not found
wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: WQ data block query control method not found
acpi PNP0C14:02: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:01)
usb 1-14: device descriptor read/64, error -71
r8169 0000:08:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
acpi device:4a: Cannot transition to power state D0 for parent in D3hot
ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.GFX0._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20210730/nsarguments-61)
ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20210730/nsarguments-61)
usb 1-14: device descriptor read/64, error -71
usb 1-14: device descriptor read/64, error -71
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 122124 [ PRIVRING ]
usb 1-14: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 1-14: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 1-14: device not accepting address 6, error -71
usb 1-14: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 1-14: Device not responding to setup address.
usb 1-14: device not accepting address 7, error -71
usb usb1-port14: unable to enumerate USB device
kauditd_printk_skb: 18 callbacks suppressed
systemd-sysv-generator[887]: SysV service '/etc/rc.d/init.d/livesys' lacks a native systemd unit file. Automatically generating a unit file for compatibility. Please update package to include a native systemd unit file, in order to make it more safe and robust.
systemd-sysv-generator[887]: SysV service '/etc/rc.d/init.d/livesys-late' lacks a native systemd unit file. Automatically generating a unit file for compatibility. Please update package to include a native systemd unit file, in order to make it more safe and robust.
ipmi_si: Unable to find any System Interface(s)
systemd-journald[908]: File /var/log/journal/f77120fe512e49eaba005ed0ca8db1dd/system.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
systemd-journald[908]: File /var/log/journal/f77120fe512e49eaba005ed0ca8db1dd/user-1000.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 122124 [ PRIVRING ]
```

Result for `sudo lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:7070 Lite-On Technology Corp. Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 056a:0314 Wacom Co., Ltd PTH-451 [Intuos pro (S)]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Maybe try resetting BIOS settings? Any BT related messages in dmesg?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov i have updated my post for dmesg

Comment: Please add the output of `dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn` as well.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Done

Comment: Lastly please show `sudo lsusb` output.

Comment: i have that, but the bluetooth is integrated in the pc >
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:7070 Lite-On Technology Corp. Integrated Camera 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 056a:0314 Wacom Co., Ltd PTH-451 [Intuos pro (S)] 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: Please edit your question and post it as preformatted text. ``` ``` Comments with this info are near impossible to read.

Comment: it's done :) is the bluetooth linked to the usb device ? in my case the bluetooth is a chipset

Comment: It's weird, your kernel errors don't match your `lsusb` output: `usb 1-14: device not accepting address 7, error -71` - your BT adapter could be dead but I'm only 10% sure about that. All the BT adapters I've ever seen work via USB and are USB devices. Please try using windows 10 enterprise trial - Linux doesn't always support all the devices perfectly.